# How get string git@... without scm:git:ssh:// and without developerConnection from pom.xml?

Tags: regular-expression

I have pom.xml:

```
<scm>
<developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@gitlab.com:anton_patsev/maven-release-example3.git</developerConnection>
<tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

How get string git@gitlab.com:anton_patsev/maven-release-example3.git from pom.xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
string=$(cat pom.xml | grep developerConnection | sed -e s/\<developerConnection\>scm:git:ssh://g)
echo string
echo $string
developerConnection=$(echo ${string//[[:blank:]]/} | cut -c 3- | sed s/developerConnection//g |  head -c-4)
echo developerConnection
developerConnection=$(echo $developerConnection| sed 's/gitlab.tools.russianpost.ru\//gitlab.tools.russianpost.ru:/g')
echo developerConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp should **not** be used for parsing xml/html data. Markup data is not "obliged" to keep tags or content text on single line. 
Use a proper xml/html parsers like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'scm/developerConnection/text()' pom.xml
scm:git:ssh://git@gitlab.com:anton_patsev/maven-release-example3.git
```